# Visualize attention area

Tags: visualization, computer-vision, transformer, attention-mechanism

I wonder how people draw a network's attention area on a single input.

Such as:

[image]

Any hint is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called **Class Activation Maps**. An starter could be [this](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/) tutorial in keras. For an extensive overview of the topic, browse [this](https://github.com/jacobgil/pytorch-grad-cam) pytorch repository.